# How to read gmail message content and search for links only, then save it somewhere

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

I would like to write a script, which reads email content, which will contain links to some images. Is there a script to read message content and save this link to txt which will be on google drive ?

Right now I have this, which somehow works, but generates 2 files.

```js
function test() 
{
  var BouncedEmails = GmailApp.search("label:Inbox .png ");

  for( var i=0;i<BouncedEmails.length;i++)
  {
    var Gmessage = GmailApp.getMessagesForThread(BouncedEmails[i]);

    for(var j=0;j<Gmessage.length;j++)
    {
      var body = Gmessage[j].getPlainBody();
      var fileName,newFile; //Declare variable names
      
      fileName = "Export" + new Date().toString().slice(0,24) + ".txt";//Create a new file name with date on end
      
      newFile = DriveApp.createFile(fileName,body);
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

current script generates a txt file to Google Drive, which contains:

https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png
something
https://i.redd.it/9xzdfgdfg8o21.jpg
somethingg
https://i.redd.it/9xwer2342dd8o21.jpg

The mail from which script generated file:
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5WAie.png)

Comment: Is this an answer to your problem or are you providing extra details?